# Python Celery chord raises ChordError even when error is handled by callback

Tags: python, celery, celery-task, celeryd

I have this problem in a larger application, but have reduced it to the following MRE.

I have a Celery chord consisting of two parallel tasks feeding into one final tasks. It's expected that tasks might occasionally permanently fail for external reasons, simulated here by raising `Exception`. I wish to handle that error with a custom error handler, and not cause any unhandled execptions in the Celery worker process.

Here is the definition of my three example tasks in a file I call `canvastest.py`.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('canvastest', backend='redis://localhost', broker='redis://localhost')

@app.task(throws=(Exception,),)
def t1(x):
    print("t1")
    return x


@app.task(throws=(Exception,),)
def t2(x):
    print("t2")
    return x


@app.task(throws=(Exception,),)
def t3(x):
    print("t3")
    return x

@app.task()
def error_handler(*args, **kwargs):
    print("Error handler")
```

I build my chord as follows in the file `main.py`

```py
from canvastest import t1, t2, t3, error_handler
from celery import chord

if __name__ == '__main__':

    combined_task = chord((t1.s(1), t2.s(2)),t3.s()).on_error(error_handler.si())

    combined_task()
```

To run it I first start a local redis instance by running `docker run -p 6379:6379 redis` then I run the worker `celery -A canvastest worker` and the main application `python main.py`

The log output of the worker then as expected looks as follows

```
[2023-04-20 13:59:00,840: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-16] t1
[2023-04-20 13:59:00,842: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] t2
[2023-04-20 13:59:00,854: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-16] t3
```

If I modify t3 to fail by changing it as

```py
@app.task(throws=(Exception,),)
def t3(x):
    print("t3")
    raise Exception()
    return x
```

the logs correctly looks as follows

```
[2023-04-20 14:00:18,078: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-16] t1
[2023-04-20 14:00:18,080: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] t2
[2023-04-20 14:00:18,090: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-16] t3
[2023-04-20 14:00:18,092: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-16] Error handler
```

but if we move the error to t1 or t2 as

```
@app.task(throws=(Exception,),)
def t2(x):
    print("t2")
    raise Exception()
    return x
```

then this happens

```
[2023-04-20 14:01:31,667: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-16] t1
[2023-04-20 14:01:31,668: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] t2
[2023-04-20 14:01:31,675: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-1] Chord '3336718d-57e3-41e0-b62d-4fad8ae9cc62' raised: ChordError('Dependency ffdd942e-cfe9-498f-a4b1-9d3a80a9ee45 raised Exception()')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jerkern/celery_mre/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 451, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jerkern/celery_mre/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 734, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jerkern/celery_mre/canvastest.py", line 15, in t2
    raise Exception()
Exception

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jerkern/celery_mre/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 520, in on_chord_part_return
    resl = [unpack(tup, decode) for tup in resl]
  File "/home/jerkern/celery_mre/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 520, in <listcomp>
    resl = [unpack(tup, decode) for tup in resl]
  File "/home/jerkern/celery_mre/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 426, in _unpack_chord_result
    raise ChordError(f'Dependency {tid} raised {retval!r}')
celery.exceptions.ChordError: Dependency ffdd942e-cfe9-498f-a4b1-9d3a80a9ee45 raised Exception()
[2023-04-20 14:01:31,676: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-1] Error handler
```

There is now an unhandled exception and stack trace in the log. This is the problem, and I wish to get rid of that. The error has already been handled by the `error_handler` method, and I don't wish to pollute the logs by surplus exceptions and stack traces.

Is there a way to silence this, or is it a bug in celery? My expectation would be that the error_handler is invoked in the same way regardless of which of the three tasks raises the exception, and that not further exceptions are raised and logged as a side-effect of the task failing (since that is expected behavior).

Comment: I opened an issue in the celery repo, since I expect this is a bug https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/8211